# How can create a macro in VBA that displays text if result=0 in Excel?

Tags: vba

I want to create a macro in Excel that automatically displays "NA" if the cell formula is equal to zero, for all selected cells (without deleting the formula in the cell). How can I achieve this in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You may change your formula by adding an `IF`, like the `mod` formula `=IF(MOD(A2,B2)=0,"N/A",MOD(A2,B2))` shown as blow:

```
 Number    Divisor    Result 
 1         2          1 
 2         2          N/A 
 3         2          1 
 4         2          N/A
```

I also created a macro to do this automatically. After selected an area, you may execute the macro to see the result.

```
Sub Test()

  'Get the selection area

   For Each cell In Selection
      If cell.Formula <> "" And cell.Value <> "N/A" Then
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            OldFormula = Right(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1)
            cell.Formula = "=IF(" & OldFormula & "=0," & Chr(34) & "N/A" & Chr(34) & "," & OldFormula & ")"
        End If
      End If
   Next cell

End Sub
```